# vim: how to prevent yanking to clipboard from replacing unnamed register?

Tags: vim

Whenever I yank text to the clipboard register, the content of the unnamed register changes.

For example, yanking the word "This" to the unnamed register:

```
This is a test
^
yw
```

The unnamed register now contains "This".

Then yanking the word "test" to the * register:

```
This is a test
          ^
          "*yw
```

The * register contains now "test".

I expect the unnamed register to still contain "This". However, if I do a simple put, "test" is insert:

```
This is a test
              ^
              p

This is a test test
```

From my understanding, yanking to the clipboard register should not replace the unnamed register. Is there a way of preventing this from happening?

Vim version: 8.2

Comment: @Matt It answers it partially. I didn't know that the unnamed register is a pointer to the last used register. I thought it was a sperate one. I guess if I need to keep my previous yank I need to yank it to a specific register.

Comment: As unnamed register doesn't really exist, any "default" yank goes into register 0 (zero). I actually mentioned this in my answer too.

Comment: @Matt Right. It makes sense now. So basically I need to get used to the idea that the default register doesn't exist. So your answer in the linked question actually answers my question.